# How to save Facebook user's data into our own database who like my app, page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there any way to save data of Facebook's users into my own database who has liked my applivation on page.

I wanted to know who liked my app, page and want to save those details into my database

Comment: Be more descriptive - if you are talking about a Like button which appears on your website, you can use javascript and Facebooks `onSubscribe` API function. Otherwise, if you are talking about a Like button on your app on Facebook, you can't track who clicks it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it & the way of doing it, depends on

do you mean Like button top of the page or like button like what is for websites ?

please explain more

Comment: I know about Like button and other plugins. But i want to store information of Facebook user who has like my website. There is a facebook like button on a website.

Comment: I heard some things about a JSON script which can do it.

Comment: you want store information about who liked your page with the person's Facebook uid ?

Comment: ya.. user id or email !! i heard about JSON script which do that !! but i guess it is for applications of facebook !! please suggest

Comment: if you try to get uid of users who liked your page in you website you can do it by making a fb app & getting user ids but if you want to get users who liked a page on your website i dont think it be possible

Answer (score 0):

You can get only a limited amount of data about a person who has liked your page. It is contained within the signed_request parameter that is posted to all facebook tabs when they load.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

For an anonymous user who has not authenticated your app, the information you can get is
locale,
country,
age (this is an object containing minimum and maximum age - which you can use to control age restricted content on your page, but which doesn't give you a very accurate user age)

If you want more information than this, you need to authenticate the user with OAuth, and request that they give you permission to access their data - there is plenty of documentation on this.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login